# У иконки флага серый фон

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, дизайн

В разделе "Важное на мете" под флажком видно серый квадрат, хотя по идее он должен быть на жёлтом фоне блока.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Просто дождитесь второго апреля!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, первого апредя тоже надо фиксить баги ;)

Comment: Завтра можно будет вешать метку [meta-tag:статус-не-воспроизводится] и закрыть этот вопрос.

Comment: @defaultlocale, ответ пиши ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это не флаг, это [иконка битого изображения](https://www.quora.com/Who-designed-the-broken-image-icons) из Netscape Navigator: [image: broken image].

На Meta.SO [Cody Gray пишет](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382100/why-icons-were-not-in-time-travel/382101#382101), что все иконки сайтов специально заменяются на этот квадратик чтобы усилить сходство с сайтами 90-х:

> All of the icons are actually set to "broken image" icons, which made their first appearance in the late 1990s with Netscape Navigator. As the footer tells you, this site is "best viewed in Netscape 3.0".